# C++ pointer scoping issue

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm running into some C++ scoping problems, and I can't figure out why. I've simplified this a lot from the original problem by making everything public. Can someone help me understand why vec is null at the end of main? How do I get Get1stVec(...) to actually set vec to something which doesn't get immediately destroyed?

```
class Vec2
{
public:
    float x, y;
    Vec2(float x_, float y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
    Vec2() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) {}
};

class Polygon
{
public:
    void AddVertex(Vec2 vert) { verts.push_back(vert); }
    std::vector<Vec2> verts;
};

void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2* vec)
{
    Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    vec = tmp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Polygon poly;
    poly.AddVertex(Vec2(1.0f, 1.0f));
    Vec2* vec = nullptr;
    Get1stVec(&poly, vec);
    vec->x = 2.0f; // vec is nullptr here. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass the ponter `vec` by value, where to change what it points to in a function, you need to pass a reference to a pointer or a pointer to a pointer (or `return tmp;`). Not sure why you even need a pointer here though.

Comment: You need to pass a reference: `void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2*& vec)`

Answer (score 2):

```
void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2* vec)
```

modifies the local *copy* of `vec`, not the variable `vec` you have in your `main`. They're different variables.

You may pass a reference instead or alternatively redesign and get rid of all those useless pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your `Get1stVec` signature. You are trying to modify the local pointer `vec`. So **its** address has be passed to function to get a valid modification. The earlier declaration would have worked if the `vec` pointer in main already had some address to begin with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vec2
{
public:
    float x, y;
    Vec2(float x_, float y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
    Vec2() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) {}
};

class Polygon
{
public:
    void AddVertex(Vec2 vert) { verts.push_back(vert); }
    std::vector<Vec2> verts;
};

void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2** vec)
{
    Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    *vec = tmp;
}

int main()
{
    Polygon poly;
    poly.AddVertex(Vec2(1.0f, 1.0f));
    Vec2* vec = nullptr;
    Get1stVec(&poly, &vec);   //passing address of the vec pointer
    vec->x = 2.0f; // vec is nullptr here. Why? - **Look at previous line**
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters are its local variables. They are initialized by copies of the supplied arguments.

You can imagine this function

```
void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2* vec)
{
    Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    vec = tmp;
}
```

and its call

```
Get1stVec(&poly, vec);
```

the following way (I renamed parameters that they would differ from arguments)

```
void Get1stVec(/*Polygon* poly1, Vec2* vec1*/)
{
    Polygon* poly1 = &poly;
    Vec2* vec1 = vec;

    Vec2* tmp = &poly1->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    vec1 = tmp;
    ^^^^
}
```

As you cann see it is the parameter that was changed not the argument.

You should pass an argument by reference if you want that it would be changed in a function.

For example

```
void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2* &vec )
                                    ^^^^
{
    Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    vec = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in the code. `vec` in the `_tmain()` function will not change the value in this example. It is a `nullptr` because you initialized it as a `nullptr`.

To understand why. we have to examine `Get1stVec`:

```
void Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2* vec)
{
    Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0); // tmp gets a valid pointer here.
    vec = tmp;
}
```

Note: In `Get1stVec` it is possible to access the vec (if it is valid) pointer and dereference it. Here it is a `nullptr`, to accessing or dereferencing would lead to an access violation.

`poly->verts.at(0);` will return a copy of `Vec2` from the `verts vector`. As we are in the `Get1stVec` function, that copy is created on the stack.

Note: Stack variables and object life only as long as the function is executed. So do the passed parameter values to the function. The same applies to locally defined variables and objects.

So

```
Vec2* tmp = &poly->verts.at(0);
```

tmp is a locally defined pointer and lives on the stack. The result of `poly->verts.at(0);` lives also on the stack.

Now

```
poly->verts.at(0);
```

`vec = tmp;` is assigned. `vec` is a passed parameter, it lives also on the stack.

When the code execution leaves `Get1stVec`, the stack will be unwind and all information is lost.

If you want to save the information of the stack unwind, then using pass a reference to your pointer to `Get1stVec` like this:

```
Get1stVec(Polygon* poly, Vec2&* vec)
```

parameter `vec` is now referencing a pointer to `vec` in the `_tmain` function and not the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `Vec2` pointer to `Get1stVec` by value. In other words, you are taking a *copy* of the pointer inside the function. If you modify that local pointer to point at something else it will not change the pointer in the `main` function.

You could pass the pointer by reference `Vec2*&` but it would be more idiomatic to return the pointer by value from `Get1stVec`. In this case the pointer cannot be null so it would be even better to return a reference instead of a pointer:

```
Vec2& Get1stVec(Polygon& poly) 
{
    return poly.verts.at(0);
}

int main() 
{
    Polygon poly;
    poly.AddVertex(Vec2(1.0f, 1.0f));
    Vec2& vec = Get1stVec(poly);
    vec.x = 2.0f; // vec is nullptr here. Why?
}
```

I've also changed `Get1stVec` to take `Polygon` by reference instead of pointer.

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/txGXuVQxK4ClGsyC).